# error while converting keras model with 2 input to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, quantization, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a tf2.keras model to tflite, but get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid input size: expected 2 items got 1 items.
```

my network is Siamese - it has 2 inputs that both are fed into the same backbone:

```py
input_shape = (image_size, image_size, 3)
left_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name='left_input')
right_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name='right_input')

# define base model:
general_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = build_mobilenet(inputs=general_input) # builds a standart mobilenet model
backbone_model = tf.keras.Model(general_input, x)

# run both examples:
left_features = backbone_model(left_input)
right_features = backbone_model(right_input)
output = tf.keras.layers.Subtract(name='diff')([left_features, right_features])
# continue run some more actions over the output tensor...
```

during training my dataset object return a dictionary of input and the label: `{'left_input': im_left, 'right_input': im_right}, label`

when trying to qunatize the model I have a representative dataset objects that returns only the inputs (without the label): `return {'left_input': left, 'right_input': right}`.

the tflite code used for qunatization:

```py
data_generator = DataProvider(num_images=10)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(float32_model_path, compile=False)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
converter.representative_dataset = data_generator 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

The error occurs when calling to `converter.convert()`. Does anyone understand what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I have worked with Siamese network. Please try to do `print([layer.name for layer in model.layers])` and give me the output.

Comment: do you mean the name of the float32 model layers? it's actually a very long output but I only use builtin tf.keras layers - DepthwizeConv2D, Conv2D, Add, BatchNorm, Relu and Softmax.

Comment: Do you have a .h5 file available? Is it possible to send it to farmaker47@gmail.com? I have to see the layers